# How to fill by dotted water below rounded corners?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to get a figure like this

[image]

My code so far is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale = 2, line join = round, line cap = round]
   %\draw[step = 1cm, gray, very thin] (0,-4) grid (8,8);
    \draw (4.3,0) arc (0:90:1cm);
    \draw (4.7,0) arc (180:90:1cm);

    \draw (2,1) -- (3.3,1);
    \draw (5.7,1) -- (7,1);

    % thin pipe
    \draw (4.3,3) -- (4.3,-2);
    \draw (4.7,3) -- (4.7,-2);

    % glass
    \draw (2,1.5) -- (2,-3);
    \draw (7,1.5) -- (7,-3);
    \draw (2,-3) -- (7,-3);

    \foreach \x in {-2.9,-2.7,...,0.6}
    {\draw[gray!30, dash pattern = on 4pt off 4pt] ([xshift = 4pt] + 2cm, \x cm) -- ++([xshift = -4pt]5.0cm, 0);}
    \foreach \x in {-3.0,-2.8,...,0.5}
    {\draw[gray!30, dash pattern = on 4pt off 4pt] ([xshift = 4pt] + 1.9cm, \x cm) -- ++([xshift = -4pt]5.0cm, 0);}

    % depressed mercury in the thin pipe
    \draw (4.7,-0.2) arc (0:180:0.2);

    \node at (6,-2) {mercury};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How to fill around rounded corners.

Comment: You can use the `\clip` tikz macro to limit the drawing area of following commands.

Comment: This can be done even without a clip. It's an area, draw the border and fill it with the pattern.

Comment: @Alenanno is there a fill pattern which creates these dashed lines?

Comment: Maybe you could use the 'rounded corners' option instead of the arc in the path, this will give a more realistic and uniform view of the mercury surface. By the way, the contact could also be corrected for the inside of the beaker not only for the inner tube.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, the key is to `\clip` the image. For that, you should create the area which has to be clipped in one command, instead of multiple commands. With `cycle`, you return to the point where the command was started (here: `(2,1)`).

```
\draw[clip] (2,1) -- (3.3,1) arc (90:0:1cm) --  (4.3,-0.2) arc (180:0:0.2) -- 
    (4.7,0) arc (180:90:1cm) -- (7,1) -- (7,-3) -- (2,-3) -- cycle;
```

This draws the path, and clips everything which follows to that area. So simply place your two `\foreach` loops after this.

As shown in the example below, you should place these commands inside `\begin{scope} ... \end{scope}`, which allows you to create not-clipped paths afterwards.  Otherwise, the thin pipe would always be below the filling.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

% Glass
\draw (2,1.5) -- (2,-3) -- (7,-3) -- (7,1.5);

% Fill
\begin{scope}
    \clip (2,1) -- (3.3,1) arc (90:0:1cm) --  (4.3,-0.2) arc (180:0:0.2) -- (4.7,0) arc (180:90:1cm) -- (7,1) -- (7,-3) -- (2,-3) -- cycle;
    \foreach \x in {-2.9,-2.7,...,2}
        {\draw[gray!30, dash pattern = on 4pt off 4pt] ([xshift = 4pt] + 2cm, \x cm) -- ++([xshift = -4pt]5.0cm, 0);}
    \foreach \x in {-3.0,-2.8,...,2}
        {\draw[gray!30, dash pattern = on 4pt off 4pt] ([xshift = 4pt] + 1.9cm, \x cm) -- ++([xshift = -4pt]5.0cm, 0);}
    \draw (2,1) -- (3.3,1) arc (90:0:1cm) --  (4.3,-0.2) arc (180:0:0.2) -- (4.7,0) arc (180:90:1cm) -- (7,1) -- (7,-3) -- (2,-3) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

% Thin pipe
\draw (4.3,3) -- (4.3,-2);
\draw (4.7,3) -- (4.7,-2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

As I suggested in a previous comment, you could use this code with the 'rounded corners' option (you can adjust the value of the radius) as an alternative to arc (you only need to split the filling in three parts):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

% Fill
\begin{scope}
\clip {[rounded corners=6](2,-3) -- (2,1) -- (4.3,1)  -- (4.3,-0.2)}  -- (4.3,-3) -- cycle;
\foreach \x in {-2.9,-2.7,...,2}
    {\draw[gray!30, dash pattern = on 4pt off 4pt] ([xshift = 4pt] + 2cm, \x cm) -- ++([xshift = -4pt]5.0cm, 0);}
\foreach \x in {-3.0,-2.8,...,2}
    {\draw[gray!30, dash pattern = on 4pt off 4pt] ([xshift = 4pt] + 1.9cm, \x cm) -- ++([xshift = -4pt]5.0cm, 0);}
\draw {[rounded corners=6](2,-2) -- (2,1) -- (4.3,1)  -- (4.3,-0.2)}  -- (4.3,-2);  
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip {[rounded corners=6](4.3,-3) -- (4.3,-0.2) -- (4.7,-0.2)}  -- (4.7,-3) -- cycle;
\foreach \x in {-2.9,-2.7,...,2}
    {\draw[gray!30, dash pattern = on 4pt off 4pt] ([xshift = 4pt] + 2cm, \x cm) -- ++([xshift = -4pt]5.0cm, 0);}
\foreach \x in {-3.0,-2.8,...,2}
    {\draw[gray!30, dash pattern = on 4pt off 4pt] ([xshift = 4pt] + 1.9cm, \x cm) -- ++([xshift = -4pt]5.0cm, 0);}
\draw {[rounded corners=6, pattern=north east lines](4.3,-2) -- (4.3,-0.2) -- (4.7,-0.2)}  -- (4.7,-2); 
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip {[rounded corners=6](4.7,-0.2) -- (4.7,1)   -- (7,1)} -- (7,-3) -- (4.7,-3) -- cycle;
\foreach \x in {-2.9,-2.7,...,2}
    {\draw[gray!30, dash pattern = on 4pt off 4pt] ([xshift = 4pt] + 2cm, \x cm) -- ++([xshift = -4pt]5.0cm, 0);}
\foreach \x in {-3.0,-2.8,...,2}
    {\draw[gray!30, dash pattern = on 4pt off 4pt] ([xshift = 4pt] + 1.9cm, \x cm) -- ++([xshift = -4pt]5.0cm, 0);}
\draw {[rounded corners=6](4.7,-2) -- (4.7,-0.2) -- (4.7,1) -- (7,1)} -- (7,-2);
\end{scope}

% Glass
\draw (2,1.5) -- (2,-3) -- (7,-3) -- (7,1.5);

% Thin pipe
\draw (4.3,3) -- (4.3,-2);
\draw (4.7,3) -- (4.7,-2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which will give you this picture:

[image]